# Solving VBA Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing a run-time error '424' on the 'For Each Cell In rg' line. Could anyone help me with this please?

```
Sub extract()

Dim i As Integer
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim FileLocation As String
Dim rg, Cell As Range

FileLocation = "C:\\xxxxx"

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileLocation)
Set rg = OpenBook.Sheet2.Range("B1", Sheet2.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Cell
i = 0

For Each Cell In rg
    If Sheet1.Range("G2").Value = Cell Then
        i = i + 1
        Sheet1.Range("G7").Offset(i, 0).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Did your code really not error on the line `Set rg = OpenBook.Sheet2.Range(...)` ?

Comment: There are many things "wrong" in your code but to name a few - 1) `Dim rg, Cell As Range` should be `Dim rg As Range, Cell As Range`. What you have is declaring `rg` as Variant. 2) `Set rg = OpenBook.Sheet2.Range("B1", Sheet2.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Cell` looks wrong on several parts. Assuming that you want to get the cells in a worksheet named `Sheet2` in `OpenBook` then it would be something like `Set rg = OpenBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Cells`. You can't refer a worksheet in other workbook by its codename directly.